# Group by and filter the *second* half of rows in each group

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I filter to include just the *second* half of rows for each group? In the real dataframe, the number of rows per group is dynamic so you can't hard-code the number of rows and most functions won't work here. I tried:

```
d <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 y = c(20, 30, 45, 54, 65, 78, 97, 102, 123, 156, 234, 456, 322, 346, 234))

d %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% (n()/2:n()))
```

But got a wacky result. I think this should be a pretty easy fix, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Here X is assumed to be group?

Comment: Yes, it's grouping by x.

Comment: `row_number() > n()/2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not the following?

```
d %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  filter(row_number() >= n()/2) 

# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   x [5]
       x     y
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    78
 2     2    97
 3     3   102
 4     4   123
 5     5   156
 6     1   234
 7     2   456
 8     3   322
 9     4   346
10     5   234
```